# Ordinary differential equation that models mixing problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having some trouble finding dQ/dt of this problem. I've found 
dQ/dt = (0.75rt)-(Q/(10t+2)(10+r)) but my webwork says it isn't correct.

Here is the problem:

A mixing chamber initially contains 2 liters of a clear liquid. Clear liquid flows into the chamber at a rate of 10 liters per minute. A dye solution having a concentration of 0.75 kilograms per liter is injected into the mixing chamber at a constant rate of  liters per minute. When the mixing process is started, the well-stirred mixture is pumped from the chamber at a rate of 10+ liters per minute. Let Q be the amount of dye in the mixture.

Thank you.

Comment: Since fluid flows into the mixture at the same rate, $10 + r$, that it flows out, the mixture always has exactly 2 liters. Since the mixture is well mixed, the density of dye leaving is the average density of dye in the mixture, which is $\dfrac {Q \text{ Kg}}{2\text{ L}}$, not $\dfrac Q{10t + 2}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I found the answer just now. However, the second part of the question states that: Assume the mixing chamber contains 2 liters of clear liquid at time =0. How many minutes will it take for the outflow concentration to rise to within 5% of the desired concentration of 0.5 kilograms per liter? We know that r=20, how do I proceed?

Comment: You found your differential equation for $Q$. Now find the function $Q$ that satisfies it, with $Q(0) = 0$.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work. I got Q(t) = (3(10t+r)/4(r+20))+C(10t+r)^(-r/10-1), I got C= -6 with the initial value, is this correct? Even so, it gives me the wrong answer when I plug the answer I get for t into my webwork. @PaulSinclair

Comment: That $Q$ does not solve the differential equation. You can check yourself that differentiating it does not give $0.75r - Q(5 + r/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful with this sort of a problem to keep careful track of your units. So instead of just ignoring them, let's watch them carefully:

- kg = kilograms
  L = liters ("l" is more common but too easy to confuse with $1$
  here).
  M = minutes
- The time $t$ since the process started is measured in minutes.
- The rate at which the clear liquid enters is $10 \ \frac{\text L}{\text M}$.
- The rate at which the dye solution enters is $r\ \frac{\text L}{\text M}$.
- The dye solution contains $0.75\ \frac{\text kg}{\text L}$ of dye.
- Therefore dye enters the chamber at a rate of $0.75\ \frac{\text {kg}}{\text L}r \ \frac{\text L}{\text M} = 0.75r\ \frac{\text {kg}}{\text M}$
- The amount of dye in the chamber at time $t$ is $Q = Q(t)$, in kilograms.
- The volume of the chamber is $2\ \text L$.
- Therefore the density of dye in the chamber is the chamber is $\frac {Q\ \text {kg}}{2\ \text L} = \frac Q2 \frac{\text {kg}}{\text L}$
- The rate at which fluid leaves the chamber is $(10 + r)\ \frac{\text L}{\text M}$
- There dye leaves the chamber at a rate of $\frac Q2 \frac{\text {kg}}{\text L} (10 + r)\ \frac{\text L}{\text M} = Q\left(5 + \frac r2\right)\ \frac{\text {kg}}{\text M}$
- Since $Q$ is measured in kg and $t$ in minutes, the rate of change $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ has units of $\frac{\text {kg}}{\text M}$

Now the rate of change in $Q$ will be the rate at which dye enters the chamber minus the rate at which it leaves:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = \left[0.75r - Q\left(5 + \frac r2\right)\right]\ \frac{\text {kg}}{\text M}$$
$$\frac{dQ}{dt} + Q\left(5 + \frac r2\right) = 0.75r$$

We know that $r = 20\ \frac{\text L}{\text M}$, so
$$\frac{dQ}{dt} + 15Q = 15$$

Now the next step would normally be an integrating factor, but there is a quick trick that works for this case: Let $Q^* = Q - 1$. Then 
$$\frac{dQ^*}{dt} = -15Q^*\\
\int\frac{dQ^*}{Q^*} = \int -15\,dt\\
\log Q^* = -15t + C\\
Q^* = e^{-15t + C}\\
Q - 1 = Ae^{-15t}\\
Q(t) = 1 + Ae^{-15t}$$
for some constant $A$. Since $Q(0) = 1 + A\cdot 1 = 0, A = -1$. So $$Q(t) = \left(1 - e^{-15t}\right)\ \text{kg}$$